# static IV and random keys using aes-256-cbc

Tags: cryptography, aes

Are there any security risks in using a static IV if I generate a new random KEY for each set of data to encrypt?

**If** I understand correctly what the purpose of the IV is in [Cipher-block chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) mode of operation, there is no issue in doing things like this. Am I missing something?

If it helps, I am talking about something like this:

```
aes_key=$(openssl rand -hex 32)
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -base64 -K ${aes_key}  -iv "b63e541bc9ece19a1339df4f8720dcc3" -in some_file_to_encrypt -out encrypted_file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are really using a new random key for each message, you can use a fixed initialization vector, yes.

But usually you want to reuse a key for several messages - for example, as you somehow have to transfer your key to the receiver of the message, and then using a random initialization vector for each message is important to avoid showing similarities between the messages in the ciphertexts.

In your example, what else are you doing with the key? How does the receiver of the message gets the key?

Comment: the encrypted KEY - using a Public-key cryptography algorithm (RSA) - is passed together with the AES-encrypted data.